# Quad tree recursive retrieve

Tags: c++, recursion, quadtree

I am creating a quadtree and I get in some trouble with the retrieve function. This function gets down to the nodes that store objects and puts the objects in a vector called relevantObjects.
After this, it returns the relevantObjects vector. But, when it tries to do this, I see in the debugger that the vector gets wiped of its elements (goes from 4 to 0).

I don't see where I am wrong.

```
std::vector<PTR> Tree::retrieveObjects(PTR p, std::vector<PTR> relevantObjects) {

int quadrant = getQuadrant(p);

if (quadrant != -1 && nodes[0] != nullptr)
{
    nodes[quadrant]->retrieveObjects(p, relevantObjects);
}

relevantObjects.insert(relevantObjects.end(), storedObjects.begin(), storedObjects.end());


return relevantObjects; }
```

Comment: You discard any nodes from the recursive calls (by not using the function's return value), also consider passing the vector by reference all the way down and then only returning it at the top level (splitting the internal recursive function from the public one that returns the vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your recursive function `std::vector<PTR> Tree::retrieveObjects(PTR p, std::vector<PTR> relevantObjects)`, you pass parameter `relevantObjects` by value; with each call of `nodes[quadrant]->retrieveObjects(p, relevantObjects)`, a copy of vector `relevantObjects` is made, an the function then operates on the copy.

Within you function, you do not make use of the result of `[quadrant]->retrieveObjects(p, relevantObjects)`, such that the operations on the respective copy of `relevantObjects` get lost; Your function will return a copy of the very first input to `relevantObjects` after having executed `relevantObjects.insert(relevantObjects.end(), storedObjects.begin(), storedObjects.end());`.

To solve the problem, simply make parameter `relevantObjects` a "call by reference", i.e. change your signature to `std::vector<PTR> Tree::retrieveObjects(PTR p, std::vector<PTR> &relevantObjects)`, and it should work.

BTW: if you pass the vector by reference, it is unnecessary to return the result; a signature like `void Tree::retrieveObjects(PTR p, std::vector<PTR> &relevantObjects)` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! That was so obvious and yet I missed to see it.